# How to spoof dragging all elements of the same class with javascript?

Tags: javascript, mousemove, dom-events

I'm trying to make it so that a bunch of elements will move when the user holds down their mouse button and then drags the mouse. I'm trying to do this by listening to the mousedown and mousemove events and comparing their locations. The difference in the locations of is used to calculate how far to move all of the elements. The goal is that it will feel like all of the elements have been dragged. For some reason though, my approach results in the elements flying all over the place.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var mouse = {isDown : false, lastX : null, lastY : null }; 

    document.body.addEventListener("click", function(event){
        var el = document.createElement("div"); 
        el.className = "box"; 
        el.style.left = event.clientX + "px"; 
        el.style.top = event.clientY + "px"; 
        el.style.backgroundColor = "BLACK";
        el.style.width = "16px";
        el.style.height = "16px";  
        el.style.position = "absolute"; 
        document.body.appendChild(el); 
    });

    document.body.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event){
        mouse.isDown = true; 
        mouse.lastX = event.clientX; 
        mouse.lastY = event.clientY; 
    });

    document.body.addEventListener("mouseup", function(){
        mouse.isDown = false; 
        mouse.lastX = null; 
        mouse.lastY = null; 
    }); 

    var removePx = function(string){return string.substring(0, string.length -2);}  

    document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event){
        console.log("move (" + event.clientX + "," + event.clientY + ")"); 

        if(mouse.isDown){
            var deltaX = event.clientX - mouse.lastX; 
            var deltaY = event.clientY - mouse.lastY; 

            console.log("DeltaX " + deltaX); 
            console.log("DeltaY " + deltaY); 

            var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("box"); 
            for(var i = 0; i<boxes.length; i++){
                var box = boxes[i];
                box.style.left = removePx(box.style.left) + deltaX + "px"; 
                box.style.top = removePx(box.style.top) + deltaY + "px"; 
            }

            mouse.lastX = event.clientX; 
            mouse.lastY = event.clientY; 
        }

    });
}
```

What's going wrong here? Also, is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your code, i'd say that `transform` is preferrable regarding positioning for this kind of thing (instead of left/top) - see the discussion http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/.

Anyway, i didn't take a closer look at your code, but instead, tried a solution myself to what i understood of it. I just used a simple pattern regarding drag and drop which is:

1. onmousedown - setState to moving, store the clicked point, get the current matrix of the transformation applied
2. onmousemove - calculate dx, dy, accumulate this differences in the matrix, update current x and y in the state
3. onmouseup - just remove the moving state

Here's a snippet:

```js
var main = document.querySelector('main');
var movable = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.movable'));
var _state = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  matrix: [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
  moving: false
};

movable.forEach(function (elem) {
  elem.style.transform = 'matrix(' + _state.matrix.join(',') + ')'
});

function onMouseDown (e) {
  _state.moving = true;
  _state.x = e.clientX;
  _state.y = e.clientY;
  _state.matrix = matrixToArray(e.target.style.transform);
}

function matrixToArray (matrix) {
  return matrix
      .match(/matrix\((.*)\)/)[1]
      .split(' ')
      .join('')
      .split(',')
      .map(function (a) {
        return +a;
      });
}

function onMouseMove (e) {
  if (!_state.moving)
    return;

  var dx = e.clientX - _state.x;
  var dy = e.clientY - _state.y;

  _state.matrix[4] += dx;
  _state.matrix[5] += dy;

  var transf = 'matrix(' + _state.matrix.join(',') + ')'

  movable.forEach(function (elem) {
    elem.style.transform = transf;
  });

  _state.x = e.clientX;
  _state.y = e.clientY;
}

function onMouseUp (e) {
  _state.moving = false;
  _state.x = e.clientX;
  _state.y = e.clientY;
}

main.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
main.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);

movable.forEach(function (elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown);
});
```

```css
html,
body,
main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

#d1 { background: black; left: 10px; top: 10px;}
#d2 { background: brown; left: 70px; top: 10px;}
#d3 { background: green; left: 10px; top: 70px ;}
#d4 { background: purple; left: 70px; top: 70px ;}
```

```html
<main>
  <div id="d1" class="movable"></div>
  <div id="d2" class="movable"></div>
  <div id="d3" class="not-movable"></div>
  <div id="d4" class="movable"></div>
</main>
```

ps.: this is not all that much efficient. One can surely iterate on this and create a better version of it!